# Can we use a single appsettings.json file instead of maintaining multiple versions of appsettings.{environmentname}.json for different environments?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 and I want to achieve 2 things:

1. Using a single `appsettings.json` file instead of maintaining multiple versions of `appsettings.{environmentname}.json` for different environments
2. Remove hard-coding from the `appsettings.{environmentname}.json` file to allow (1)
   (Currently I'm hardcoding secrets like DB connection string, key vault configration details etc. for different environments in respective appsettings files which I want to remove and instead read the same secret values from Azure Key Vault where I'm already storing the same)

How can I achieve these?

Below code snippet is how I'm maintaining 2 `appsettings.{environmentname}.json` files`(Development & Release)`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var hostingEnvironment = builder.Environment;

if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true) 
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", false, true) 
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
else
{
    builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true) 
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Release.json", false, true) 
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}
```

**Note:** I did some research and understood that for `(1)` we can probably do something like:

```
 builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true) 
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", false, true) 
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

But then, assuming the fact that the app would be automatically deployed every time leveraging CI/CD, can I set the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the pipeline?

As for, `(2)`, I tried removing hardcoded secrets from appsettings.{environment}.json files and configured key vault like below but it doesn't work:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KeyVaultConfig>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVaultConfig").Bind(options));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.Configuration["KeyVaultConfig:KeyVaultUrl"]))
{
  var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(builtConfig["KeyVaultConfig:TenantID"], builtConfig["KeyVaultConfig:ClientID"], builtConfig["KeyVaultConfig:ClientKey"]);
  var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(builtConfig["KeyVaultConfig:KeyVaultUrl"]), credentials);
  //builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault...
 }
```

Comment: You *could* have just a single `appsettings.json` file, and then just have multiple sections e.g. `settings: { ...}, settings_dev: {....}, settings_prod: {.....}` within that file - one for each environment. Not sure if that's really much easier and more "approachable"..... you'd have to write some code to read out these values, per environment, too. The approach with the multiple files is the default .NET Core approach which is automatically supported by the system - so it's a lot less work on your side...

Comment: Can you please clarify "Remove hard-coding from the appSettings file" part? (it is quite obvious you can use only one file if your settings are the same for all environments... but it looks like you still want different configurations per environment?)

Comment: `appsettings.Release.json` doesn't make sense, and I think you have the wrong idea of how this system was designed. `appsettings.json` should be your release/production settings, and lower environment settings are laid on top of those, like `appsettings.UAT.json`, `appsettings.Test.json`, `appsettings.Development.json`, which are all *abesent* in the production environment.

Comment: marc_s is correct, you could have each environment configured that way, but selecting *different* configuration paths for different environments was a potential pain point in app/web.config (depending on how someone tried to solve the problem, and it was always something custom) because environment wasn't a first-class concept there. Web.{Debug|Release}.config had to do with build configuration, not deployed environment, and conflating the two was not practical. Indeed, it was problematic. Learn how the new system works so you don't recreate the same old problems.

Answer (score 1):

If in the end you are going to use CI/CD you can only need 2 files (appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json) and the default C# handling of these.

In the development one you hardcode all the configuration you need for dev.
In the standard one, you put keys that would be replaced during the CI/CD pipelines.

for example

in appsettings.development.json you have

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"myDb": "Server=myDbServer;Database=myDb;User Id=userDev;Password=myPassword;"
}
```

in appsettings.json you have

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"myDb": "#{connectionString}#"
}
```

And then replace "#{connectionString}#" with the environment value in the CI/CD pipelines configuration

If you really want to have only one file, you could try Json variable substitution like documented here [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-example) during the CI/CD pipelines, but the first approach allows you to handle secrets with vault more easily